# Django template rendering: using tags vs using views

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django, when rendering data in templates that's available through the request, we have 2 options:

1. Obtain the data in the view, and pass it to the template engine through the context:

```py
def my_view(request):
    username = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.username
        context = {'username': username}
        return render(request=request, template_name='test.html', context=context)
```

With a template that has:

```html
<p>Hello, {{ username }}<p>
```

2. Directly obtain the value from the request in the template:

```py
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request=request, template_name='test.html', context={})
```

With a template that has:

```html
<p>hello, {{ request.user.username }}</p>
```

Is there a difference between both in terms of 'correctness'?

Is `request` in the second template just to be seen as a context for the request object or are there other implications?

Comment: In this case, you don't need to do either, since both `request` and `user` are automatically available in the template thanks to the default context processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are correct, generally speaking you are most likely to encounter the following pattern

```
def my_view(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user': user}
    return render(request=request, template_name='test.html', context=context)
```

and

```
<p>hello, {{ user.username }}</p>
```

Usually you don't pass the `request`, but the `user` directly. Then since there could be many relevant `user` methods the `user.<something>` notation is used in the template.

Depending on your use case, though, if the only field you will need from the user is the username on that page, there's nothing wrong with passing it directly.